# How to customize JSF conversion message 'must be a number consisting of one or more digits'?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, numbers, converters, message

I have an input text that is mapped to a `Long` property.

```
private Long length;
```

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.length}" />
```

When I enter non-digits in that input text, I get the following conversion error:

> myForm:myField: 'someText' must be a number consisting of one or more digits.

I was wondering how to customize this message to:

> length must be a number greater than zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Either* use the input component's `converterMessage` attribute:

```html
<h:inputText converterMessage="length must be a number greater than zero" />
```

*(and don't forget to use `<f:validateLongRange>` to prevent users being able to enter negative values and supply a `validatorMessage`!)*

*Or* create a properties file in the classpath which overrides the default message of the builtin JSF `LongConverter`:

```
javax.faces.converter.LongConverter.LONG = length must be a number greater than zero
```

and is been registered as message bundle in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <message-bundle>com.example.CustomMessages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

The above example assumes that the file name is `CustomMessages.properties` and is been placed in `com.example` package. You can name and place it wherever you want.

You can find an overview of all message keys like `javax.faces.converter.LongConverter.LONG` and their default values in chapter 2.5.2.4 of [the JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) which is also copypasted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092267/jsf-myfaces-converter-resource-bundle-messages/3092896#3092896).

Comment: Does EL work here? like - converterMessage="#{messages.errorMessage}" This is for JSF 1.2. I tried by giving plain text. It works fine. But with EL, it does not work. Any changes to be done to support EL?