# Custom JSF validator message for a single input field

Tags: validation, jsf, message

I'd like to have different validation messages for every validator for different input fields.

Is it possible in JSF to have a different validation messages for a single validator (e.g. `<f:validateLongRange>`) for every input field?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. The easiest, just set the `validatorMessage` attribute of the `UIInput` component.

   ```xml
   <h:inputText ... validatorMessage="Please enter a number between 0 and 42">
       <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="42" />
   </h:inputText>
   ```

   However, this is also used when you use other validators. It will override all messages of other validators attached to the input field, including `required="true"` and Bean Validation such as `@NotNull`. Not sure if that would form a problem then. If so, then head to following ways.
2. Create a custom validator which extends the validator of interest, such as [`LongRangeValidator`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/faces/validator/longrangevalidator) in your specific case, wherein you catch the `ValidatorException` of the `super.validate()` call and then rethrow it with the desired custom message. E.g.

   ```xml
   <h:inputText ...>
       <f:validator validatorId="yourLongRangeValidator" />
       <f:attribute name="longRangeValidatorMessage" value="Please enter a number between 0 and 42" />
   </h:inputText>
   ```

   with

   ```java
   @FacesValidator("yourLongRangeValidator")
   public class YourLongRangeValidator extends LongRangeValidator {

       public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object convertedValue) throws ValidatorException {
           setMinimum(0); // If necessary, obtain as custom f:attribute as well.
           setMaximum(42); // If necessary, obtain as custom f:attribute as well.

           try {
               super.validate(context, component, convertedValue);
           } catch (ValidatorException e) {
               String message = (String) component.getAttributes().get("longRangeValidatorMessage");
               throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(message));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use [OmniFaces `<o:validator>`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/validator) which allows setting a different validator message on a per-validator basis:

   ```
    <h:inputText ...>
        <o:validator validatorId="jakarta.faces.Required" message="Please fill out this field" />
        <o:validator validatorId="jakarta.faces.LongRange" minimum="0" maximum="42" message="Please enter a number between 0 and 42" />
    </h:inputText>
   ```

#### See also:

- [Change the default message "Validation Error: Value is required" to just "Value is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155684/change-the-default-message-validation-error-value-is-required-to-just-value/)
- [How to customize JSF conversion message 'must be a number consisting of one or more digits'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980037/customize-the-error-mesage-must-be-a-number-consisting-of-one-or-more-digits/)
- [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle/)
- [JSF converter resource bundle messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092267/jsf-converter-resource-bundle-messages/)

Comment: I will go for number 2 as I need different messages for different validation errors as well. Your solution approved my fear that I would need a solution beyond standard behaviour.