# javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION vs javax.faces.converter.*

Tags: jsf, properties, localization, type-conversion, converters

The jsf-api.jar contains various localized Messages.properties files that contain, on the one hand a `javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION` key as well as on the other hand various `javax.faces.converter.*` keys.

My questions are:

- When is the first key used, when is the second key used?
- Where is this documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION` message will be used when the `ConverterException` didn't contain a faces message and the component didn't specify the `converterMessage` attribute. In other words, it's the default/fallback message. The message identifier is specified by the [`UIInput#CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID) constant which is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID) as follows:

> ## `CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID`
>
> `public static final java.lang.String CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID`
>
> The message identifier of the [`FacesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) to be created if a conversion error occurs, and neither the page author nor the `ConverterException` provides a message.
>
> #### See Also:
>
> [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.component.UIInput.CONVERSION_MESSAGE_ID)

---

The `javax.faces.converter.*` messages will be used when the in the message identifier specified standard JSF converter has failed a specific conversion task. The standard JSF converters are listed in class summary of the [`javax.faces.convert` package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/package-summary.html). E.g. `java.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.*` message identifiers will be used by [`DateTimeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html) which has some message identifier constants listed in its field summary like [`DateTimeConverter#DATE_ID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html#DATE_ID) with a constant value of [`"javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.DATE_ID) which is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html#DATE_ID) as follows:

> ## `DATE_ID`
>
> `public static final java.lang.String DATE_ID`
>
> The message identifier of the [`FacesMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) to be created if the conversion to `Date` fails. The message format string for this message may optionally include the following placeholders:
>
> - `{0}` replaced by the unconverted value.
> - `{1}` replaced by an example value.
> - `{2}` replaced by a `String` whose value is the label of the input component that produced this message.
>
> #### See Also:
>
> [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter.DATE_ID)

Note that all message identifiers are listed in chapter 2.5.2.4 of [JSF specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314). See also [JSF converter resource bundle messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092267/jsf-converter-resource-bundle-messages/3092896#3092896) for a copy.